# Cabinet doors dropped after initial fitting

Tags: doors, cabinets, level, custom-cabinetry

I have built some kitchen-styled cabinets for my office. They are situated atop an 18mm mdf base as this is over carpet, in order to help get level easier.

I have ensured that the cabinet is level in x, y and z axes (or close enough), however when I have fit the doors, there is an obvious drop from one side to the other...

Yes the doors are square ;-)

[image]

I understand that this can be cause by the cabinet not being level left to right, however my spirit level shows this to not be an issue (forgive my cheap level).

[image]

I have also checked that the cabinet is plumb vertically, as I thought it could be leaning out of square, but this again doesn't seem to be an issue.

[image]

What seems strange is that the cabinet on the opposite end of my set (which also has a door fitted) **doesn't** seem to suffer from the same issue...

[image]

What am I missing here?

One thing I did notice was that I can "wiggle" the door into the correct alignment... Would this suggest that the hinges are loose or is that a normal thing?

**Note:** I should add that I have used Hafele 110 degree concealed hinges with adjustments for up/down, in/out and left/right

Comment: Neither of those bubbles are in the middle, which means that it is not level or upright.

Comment: If you can "wiggle" it into position, then the hinges are loose.

Comment: Start playing with the adjustments that the hinges offer. First thing would be up/down on the plate attached to the wall of the cabinet. Make sure those screws are tight. If they’re stripped (because mdf) you might need to install inserts.